# XPath to take textarea with contains value

Tags: selenium, xpath

I have got on textarea with `id` but the data is async from Angular http client:

```
<textarea id="fullJson" ng-model="response.payload"></textarea>
```

Some texts are written by hand when page loads. Lets say we will write "`<abc>foo</abc>`".

In my java code, I use this:

```
ExpectedConditions.presenceOfElementLocated(...)
```

The question is simple:

How to use add XML char in my XPath:

```
//textarea[@id='fullJson']
```

I try this but do not work:

```
//textarea[@id='fullJson' and contains(@value, '<')]
```

I try this but do not work:

```
//textarea[@id='fullJson' and contains(@value, 'abc')]
```

Comment: You can write xpath for html elements only. The value is coming from response and may not be able to use it in xpath.

Comment: Try this : `//textarea[@id='fullJson' and contains(., '<')]`

Comment: @sgrillon What doesn't work with `//textarea[@id='fullJson']`? What error do you see?

Comment: @DebanjanB `//textarea[@id='fullJson']` do not wait until the data. (my textarea is empty)

Comment: @KunduK, `//textarea[@id='fullJson' and contains(., '<')]` do not work

Comment: @sgrillon Can you update the question with a bit more of the outerHTML?

Comment: @DebanjanB, all is present in the question.

Comment: @Murthi, write the good reply. it is not possible check value by XPath. I use now a `ExpectedConditions.textToBePresentInElementValue(...)`

Answer (score 0):

Try This:

```
//textarea[@id='fullJson' and (@ng-model = "response.payload")]
```

or

```
//*textarea[@id='fullJson' and (@ng-model = "response.payload")]
```

If Still having issue then upload the full html code!